# If duplicates in column B, check if duplicates in employee names in column D. If yes, only count once

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

This is my data sample:

[image]

What I'm trying to do with a formula is to count the number of employees in column D of my table in relation with the data in my column B. If there are duplicates in B, the formula should count the different names in D as 1. In my data sample, I've highlighted in green the ones that should be counted to help with comprehension.

As you can see, the count ($G$4) should be 7. In this situation, the cell D10 is not counted as B9+D9 and B10+D10 are perfect duplicates. Therefore only counted once. And while B5 and B6 are duplicate case file number, D5 and D6 are different, and therefore it is counted twice.

I suppose this would require a variation of the COUNTIF formula, but for the life of me I can't seem to get it right.

English is my second language, but I've tried to be as clear as possible.

I work with Excel 2010.

Thank you!!

Comment: I count `7` your picture shows `7` but your words say `6`, which is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS(Table1[Case file],Table1[Case file],Table1[Employee],Table1[Employee]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there anyway to disregard the DIV/0 error when one of the cells is blank?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS(Table1[Case file],IF(LEN(Table1[Case file])=0,"",Table1[Case file]),Table1[Employee],IF(LEN(Table1[Employee])=0,"",Table1[Employee])))` Depending on version you may need to array enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.